# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: unknown account Web3 js

Tags: web3js, tokens, smart-contract-wallets, binance, binance-smart-chain

I am Trying to Transfer BEP20 ACC Tokens on smart contract from my binance Wallet using Web3 js Library. Following is my implementation

```
const contract = new Web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, contractAddress);
binance
                .request({
                            method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                            params: [{
                                from: from,
                                to: ADDRESS,
                                "data": contract.methods.transfer(ADDRESS, bep20_value).send({from: from}),
                                gas: 75000,
                                gasPrice: 50 * 10 ** 9,
                                "chainId": web3.utils.toHex(97)
                            }, ],
                        })
                .then((txHash) => {
                    if (txHash) {
                        console.log('done');
                        console.log(txHash);
                        //Store Your Transaction Here
                    } else {
                        console.log("Something went wrong. Please try again");
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("error",error);
                });
```

Contract **Address**, **ToAddress** and **fromAddresses** are valid but Web3 Library always throws following error:

*Uncaught (in promise) Error: **Returned error: unknown account**
at Object.ErrorResponse (web.min.js:22:365340)
at web.min.js:22:364826
at XMLHttpRequest.i.onreadystatechange (web.min.js:33:25793)*

Can Someone please help what is I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could comment, but the only way I can help you is through an answer. Do you have your private key in a .env file? If not make a .env and add that there. There is more information about .env at [How to set Environment Variables](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html)

Please add the code that you are using to this question, and I can help you with what to do with a .env from there.